# How to cause the component to re-render after an ajax request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender, react-lifecycle

Rerendering same component inside one function in ReactJs. I'm adding comment and now after that I want to rerender the same component. Can anyone help?

```
commentPost() {...
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = getToken;
        axios.post(apiBaseUrl+'v1/comments/post-comment',input)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("Comment Post",response);
          //here I want to rerender this component itself
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });...
```

Comment: React triggers component re-rendering in a case if its state is changed. You need to update component's state so it will be worth to re-render it to display updated state.

Comment: You need to set state to cause react to rerender.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that you can do to cause the same component to render

**First:** Update a state of the current component using the `setState` method.

> `setState()` will always lead to a re-render unless
>   `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false. If mutable objects are being
>   used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in
>   `shouldComponentUpdate()`, calling `setState()` only when the new
>   state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary
>   re-renders.

**Second:** You can call `forceUpdate` in case you do not want to update any state of the current component. You can call it like `this.forceUpdate()`.

> Calling `forceUpdate()` will cause `render(`) to be called on the
>   component, skipping `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This will trigger the
>   normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the
>   `shouldComponentUpdate()` method of each child. React will still only
>   update the DOM if the markup changes.

Assuming that you are performing an async request from which you are getting a response you would want to update the component's state with the data that you got and hence `setState` would be the way forward for you

Comment: how to write forceUpdate? Like this  :   component.forceUpdate(callback)

Comment: `this.forceUpdate()` is the way to call forceUpdate

Comment: I'm getting this error :   "Cannot read property 'forceUpdate' of undefined"

Comment: I've to do the setState for my all the fields ??

Comment: what do you mean, setState for all your fields

Comment: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = getToken;
    axios.post(apiBaseUrl+'v1/comments/post-comment',input)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("Comment Post",response);
      this.setState({ fields: e.target.value })       should I do like this?

Comment: You should store only those states in your component that you actually need and `this.setState({ fields: e.target.value }) ` won't do you any good since you are not getting the event object as a callback the function. You may however want to store the response on ajax request in state and that you could do by `this.setState({ comments: response }) `. I would suggest you to have a look at the React docs, they are really very helpful